# Java "Generic array creation error" for a non-generic array

Tags: java, generics, stack

I'm trying to create a Stack, but I keep getting the "generic array creation" error message for the following code, even though the type isn't generic:

```
public class MyStack<Integer> implements Stack<Integer>{

    private Integer[] array;
    private int top;

    public MyStack(){
        array=new Integer[25];
        top=0;
    }
}
```

It also doesn't work for String, or for the class I'm actually trying to use.
Before anyone asks, I'm not allowed to use lists or collections. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`Integer` in `MyStack<Integer>` defines a generic type parameter that's hiding the `java.lang.Integer` class you're trying to use. Change your class declaration to

```
public class MyStack implements Stack<Integer>{
```